# Spring Boot 3.1 Testcontainers - no connection possible

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

Hello Spring Boot Developers,

I have a simple test case and want to validate the connection. Unfortunately I can't connect to the database.

This is my test case:

```kotlin
@End2EndTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = [StartPostgresContainerExtensionTestsConfiguration::class])
@Testcontainers
class SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest(
    @Autowired private val abrechnungDbDataSource: DataSource?,
) {

    companion object {

        @Container
        @JvmStatic
        val postgresContainer = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:13.8-bullseye").also { it.start() }

        @DynamicPropertySource
        @JvmStatic
        fun datasourceProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("fonl.databases.abrechnung-db.name", postgresContainer::getDatabaseName)
            registry.add("fonl.databases.abrechnung-db.username", postgresContainer::getUsername)
            registry.add("fonl.databases.abrechnung-db.password", postgresContainer::getPassword)
            registry.add("fonl.databases.abrechnung-db.url", postgresContainer::getJdbcUrl)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `connection to database can be established`() {
        assertThat(abrechnungDbDataSource).isNotNull
        checkConnectivity(abrechnungDbDataSource!!)
    }

    private fun checkConnectivity(dataSource: DataSource) {
        dataSource.connection.isValid(3)
        val jdbcTemplate = JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        val result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT 1", Int::class.java)
        check(result == 1)
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTestConfiguration {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("fonl.databases.abrechnung-db")
    fun abrechnungDbDataSourceProperties() = DataSourceProperties()

    @Bean
    fun abrechnungDbDataSource(abrechnungDbDataSourceProperties: DataSourceProperties): DataSource =
        abrechnungDbDataSourceProperties.also {
            logDataSourceProperties(it)
        }.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build()

    private fun logDataSourceProperties(dataSourceProperties: DataSourceProperties) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled) {
            log.debug(
                "DriverClassname=${dataSourceProperties.driverClassName}; " +
                    "DataSourceName=${dataSourceProperties.name}; " +
                    "UserName=${dataSourceProperties.username}; " +
                    "Password=${dataSourceProperties.password}; " +
                    "url=${dataSourceProperties.url}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I can see in the logs, that the container is started and the properties are set correctly

```
09:36:15.892 [Test worker] INFO  tc.postgres:13.8-bullseye - Creating container for image: postgres:13.8-bullseye
09:36:15.903 [Test worker] INFO  tc.postgres:13.8-bullseye - Container postgres:13.8-bullseye is starting: 354a1f11fb796abd72af46d855d65849aac7d1e9cb41aa560941ec62b44ff82d
09:36:16.859 [Test worker] INFO  tc.postgres:13.8-bullseye - Container postgres:13.8-bullseye started in PT0.967635S
09:36:16.860 [Test worker] INFO  tc.postgres:13.8-bullseye - Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32771/test?loggerLevel=OFF)
09:36:16.867 [Test worker] INFO  d.a.f.m.t.p.SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest - Starting SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest using Java 17.0.6 with PID 7635 (started by alexander.rolfes in /Users/alexander.rolfes/sources/allianz/fonl-microlibraries/testing/test-support/test-support-postgres)
09:36:16.867 [Test worker] DEBUG d.a.f.m.t.p.SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest - Running with Spring Boot v3.1.6, Spring v6.0.14
09:36:16.867 [Test worker] INFO  d.a.f.m.t.p.SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest - The following 2 profiles are active: "test", "end2end-test"
09:36:17.477 [Test worker] DEBUG d.a.f.m.t.p.StartPostgresContainerExtensionTestsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0 - DriverClassname=org.postgresql.Driver; DataSourceName=test; UserName=test; Password=test; url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32771/test?loggerLevel=OFF
09:36:17.507 [Test worker] INFO  d.a.f.m.t.p.SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest - Started SpringBootPostgresTestcontainerTest in 4.295 seconds (process running for 5.297)
09:36:17.579 [Test worker] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
09:36:18.628 [Test worker] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:32771 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Can you tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

PS: Stackoverflow forces me to add more details. But I think this code and the logs are talking enough. Unfortunately I add here more text to fulfill the stackoverflow requirements

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out what was the problem. The default Wait strategy does not work for my setup.

The trick is to set the wait stratregy to `Wait.forListeningPort()`

in my concrete example I have to add one line before the container is starting

```kotlin
@Container
@JvmStatic
val postgresContainer = PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:13.8-bullseye").also { postgresContainer -> 
    postgresContainer.waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())
    postgresContainer.start() 
}
```